# When a current is actually a holomorphic form?

Tags: complex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, several-complex-variables

If a current $f$ of bidegree $(p,0)$  (acting on forms of bidegree $(n-p,n)$) satisfies $\bar{d}f=0$, is it true that $f$ is a holomorphic differential form?

In general, do we have any standard method to verify if a current is a smooth form or even a holomorphic form?

Comment: I might have figured it out. f is in fact also harmonic, so f is a smooth function.

Comment: Huh? Your use of the letter $f$ is confusing you.